# graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/***/channels/**/messages POST on this api is not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/fd7c1****************/channels/19***********************/messages POST on this api is not working. It was working fine until yesterday.  GET is still working fine. Post request gives me BadRequest status code 400.

[This image is of a graph explorer that is not taking a post request on beta/teams/{teamId}/channels/{channelId}/messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoMRJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar issue when I call https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams. I try to create a new team with a json (template) body.

The following properties cannot be set in the initial POST request. 
Please set them in a subsequent PATCH request: installedApps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your response but I realized that the reason that api(above) did not work for me on that day was becuase I had archived the team before hand on the code. So apparently you can not push any message to channel using graph api once the team is archived. All I had to do was to replace the archive portion of the code to the bottom of the function.

Although this is my concern whether if the Microsoft will push this api to the v1. version or not. I am really worried that they will remove this api from the beta version and my app will break again.